# where to provide NSURL value?

Tags: objective-c, firebase-realtime-database, nsurl

Every time I run the app it crashes and the console says:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'MissingDatabaseURL', reason: 'Failed to get FirebaseDatabase instance: Specify DatabaseURL within FIRApp or from your databaseForApp:URL: call.

I have the URL I don't know where to place it. I am new to objective C. This is the line that firebase say to use I Just don't know where to place the value of url.

```
+ (FIRDatabase *)databaseForApp:(FIRApp *)app URL:(NSString *)url
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the `GoogleServices-Info.plist` file that you downloaded from Firebase does not contain the URL for the database.

There are a few reasons this could be happening:

- If you are providing the configuration data in code, be sure to set the [`databaseURL` property](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasecore/api/reference/Classes/FIROptions#/c:objc(cs)FIROptions(py)databaseURL) to the correct value.
- If you are providing the configuration data through the `GoogleServices-Info.plist` file, be sure to download a new version of that file after you create the database in the Firebase console and add it to your app as before.

This is a new requirement (since a few weeks ago) as the Realtime Database is now created on-demand (instead of auto-created when the project is created), so that you can pick in what region it's created.

Also see, this question/answer for Android: [Firebase : I get in trouble when I sign in with Google](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65348685/firebase-i-get-in-trouble-when-i-sign-in-with-google/65348792#65348792)