# E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_database( 6299): Failed to handle method call

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to add a simple text to the Firebase database. I have successfully logged in using gmail and that worked properly, but when i try to add anything it gives me this error:

```
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_database( 6299): Failed to handle method call
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_database( 6299): com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to get FirebaseDatabase instance: Specify DatabaseURL within FirebaseApp or from your getInstance() call.
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_database( 6299):    at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:103)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_database( 6299):    at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:60)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_database( 6299):    at io.flutter.plugins.firebase.database.MethodCallHandlerImpl.onMethodCall(MethodCallHandlerImpl.java:236)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_database( 6299):    at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:233)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_database( 6299):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.handleMessageFromDart(DartMessenger.java:85)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_database( 6299):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(FlutterJNI.java:692)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_database( 6299):    at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_database( 6299):    at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:326)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_database( 6299):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:160)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_database( 6299):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_database( 6299):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_database( 6299):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_database( 6299):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
I/flutter ( 6299): lets gooo00000000000
E/flutter ( 6299): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(error, Failed to get FirebaseDatabase instance: Specify DatabaseURL within FirebaseApp or from your getInstance() call., null, com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to get FirebaseDatabase instance: Specify DatabaseURL within FirebaseApp or from your getInstance() call.
E/flutter ( 6299):  at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:103)
E/flutter ( 6299):  at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:60)
E/flutter ( 6299):  at io.flutter.plugins.firebase.database.MethodCallHandlerImpl.onMethodCall(MethodCallHandlerImpl.java:236)
E/flutter ( 6299):  at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:233)
E/flutter ( 6299):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.handleMessageFromDart(DartMessenger.java:85)
E/flutter ( 6299):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(FlutterJNI.java:692)
E/flutter ( 6299):  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
E/flutter ( 6299):  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:326)
E/flutter ( 6299):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:160)
E/flutter ( 6299):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
```

The code:

```
    final databaser= FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference();
    
     savePost(){
      databaser.child('cats').set({
      'id':'1',
      'name': 'yes sirr'
      }
    );
      print("lets gooo00000000000");
    
     
    }
```

[no caption](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXdjY.png)

[the error that gave me a headache](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MnADt.png)

Answer (score 1):

See the example https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_database/example
I think you have to initialise with `await Firebase.initializeApp(...)`

Answer (score 1):

As spkersten said in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65457751/209103), make sure that you call `Firebase.initializeApp(...)` before getting the database instance.

If you've done that and still get the answer, it may be that the database URL is missing from the `Google-Services.json` that you downloaded from the Firebase console. If that is the cause, you can solve it by downloading an updated `Google-Services.json` after making sure the database has been created in the console, and adding it to your app as you did before.

For more on this, see:

- [Firebase : I get in trouble when I sign in with Google](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65348685/firebase-i-get-in-trouble-when-i-sign-in-with-google/65348792#65348792) (for Android)
- [where to provide NSURL value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65368954/where-to-provide-nsurl-value/65372127#65372127) (for iOS)