# Firebase error. Please ensure that you spelled the name of your Firebase correctly

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When I try to save value to database, i am getting below error:

> Firebase error. Please ensure that you spelled the name of your Firebase correctly

Anybody know how to fix it?

Below is my app's build.gradle

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.android.armessage"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.koin:koin-android-viewmodel:$koin_version"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database-ktx:19.6.0'
}
```

Below is my fragment,
I am trying to save text("Hello world") in database onCreateView

```
    class BottomSheetFragment: BottomSheetDialogFragment() {
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val inflate = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bottom_sheet, container, false)

        val database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
        database?.setLogLevel(Logger.Level.DEBUG)
        val myRef = database!!.reference
        myRef.setValue("Hello, World!")

        return view
    }
}
```

google-services.json

```
{
  "project_info": {
    "project_number": "1262330",
    "firebase_url": "https://rt-73b76-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app",
    "project_id": "rtb76",
    "storage_bucket": "rtb76.appspot.com"
  },
  "client": [
    {
      "client_info": {
        "mobilesdk_app_id": "1:4545:f33",
        "android_client_info": {
          "package_name": "com.android.demo"
        }
      },
      "oauth_client": [
        {
          "client_id": "555677-77.apps.googleusercontent.com",
          "client_type": 3
        }
      ],
      "api_key": [
        {
          "current_key": "44545-45455"
        }
      ],
      "services": {
        "appinvite_service": {
          "other_platform_oauth_client": [
            {
              "client_id": "454545-54545.apps.googleusercontent.com",
              "client_type": 3
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "configuration_version": "1"
}
```

**Error:**

```
websocket opened
2020-12-26 23:50:37.012 3867-4287/com.android.demo D/WebSocket: ws_0 - Reset keepAlive
2020-12-26 23:50:37.014 3867-4288/com.android.demo D/WebSocket: ws_0 - ws message: {"t":"c","d":{"t":"s","d":"Firebase error. Please ensure that you spelled the name of your Firebase correctly"}}
2020-12-26 23:50:37.014 3867-4287/com.android.demo D/WebSocket: ws_0 - Reset keepAlive. Remaining: 44998
2020-12-26 23:50:37.015 3867-4287/com.android.demo D/WebSocket: ws_0 - HandleNewFrameCount: 1
2020-12-26 23:50:37.015 3867-4287/com.android.demo D/WebSocket: ws_0 - handleIncomingFrame complete frame: {t=c, d={t=s, d=Firebase error. Please ensure that you spelled the name of your Firebase correctly}}
2020-12-26 23:50:37.016 3867-4287/com.android.demo D/Connection: conn_0 - Got control message: {t=s, d=Firebase error. Please ensure that you spelled the name of your Firebase correctly}
2020-12-26 23:50:37.016 3867-4287/com.android.demo D/Connection: conn_0 - Connection shutdown command received. Shutting down...
2020-12-26 23:50:37.016 3867-4287/com.android.demo D/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Firebase Database connection was forcefully killed by the server. Will not attempt reconnect. Reason: Firebase error. Please ensure that you spelled the name of your Firebase correctly
2020-12-26 23:50:37.016 3867-4287/com.android.demo D/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Connection interrupted for: server_kill
2020-12-26 23:50:37.016 3867-4287/com.android.demo D/Connection: conn_0 - closing realtime connection
2020-12-26 23:50:37.016 3867-4287/com.android.demo D/WebSocket: ws_0 - websocket is being closed
```

Comment: Ensure that you spelled the name of your Firebase correctly.

Comment: No need to specify database name(Documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start). I  downloaded and added google-services.json correctly

Comment: If you did everything correct, it wouldn't give an error. Show your configuration.

Comment: Did you (re)download the `google-service.json` **after** you created the database in the console? If not, that could well explain this error. See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65348685/firebase-i-get-in-trouble-when-i-sign-in-with-google/65348792#65348792

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen yes, I re-downloaded google-service.json. Didn't solve my issue.
I will try to drop the project and re-create new firebase project.

Comment: It works after re-creating firebase project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, it was because I was using the `europe-west1` beta region for the RTDB. Specifying the `databaseURL` (you can find it in the Firebase RTDB console) fixed it:

```
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "####",
  // ...
  databaseURL: "https://xxx-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/",
};
```

Comment: Exactly I did the same.  initially I choosed europe-west beta region. Later I re- created project using US region

Answer (score 0):

Thanks every one for contributing. it was my first time working on firebase android project  with java and was getting that error.
After adding the data, download the google_services.json again and copy to app folder.
Then add the following dependencies in app build.gradle

```
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.0.1') 
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics
```

Answer (score 0):

that is my firebase database url which was generated automatically  in the google_services.json after adding data

```
"firebase_url": "https://fir-dec-cc5ce-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/"
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have added SHA-1 in project settings in Firebase or not.